# WooCommerce + Xero: Passing through the cart total issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a site running at: http://www.presentu.co.nz

The site is running Wordpress, WooCommerce and the Xero plugin.

The site has a feature where if a user buys a glass and uploads a logo to the site, it passes through an extra one off fee. This is added in the functions.php file as:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cp_add_custom_price' );
function cp_add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {

global $woocommerce;
foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

    //$proid = $value['product_id'];
    //$variantid = $value['variation_id'];
    //$price = $value['data']->price;
    $cartItemData = $woocommerce->cart->get_item_data($value);

    // MENU COVERS ADD LOGO $99 FEE
    if (preg_match("/Upload my logo/i", $cartItemData)) {    
        $excost = 99;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Logo set up fee', $excost, $taxable = true, $tax_class = '' );
    }
    // GLASSWARE ADD LOGO $35 FEE
    if (preg_match("/Yes, add logo/i", $cartItemData)) {    
        $excost = 35;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Logo set up fee', $excost, $taxable = true, $tax_class = '' );
    }
    // CREATIVE PRINT: BASIC
    if (preg_match("/Standard design/i", $cartItemData)) {    
        $excost = 60;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Creative print design fee', $excost, $taxable = true, $tax_class = '' );
    }
    // CREATIVE PRINT: COMPLEX
    if (preg_match("/Creative design/i", $cartItemData)) {    
        $excost = 110;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Creative print design fee', $excost, $taxable = true, $tax_class = '' );
    }

}   
}
```

This works adding one-off fees to multiple products, as I couldn't find a solution off the shelf. The fee is added to the cart total on invoice.

For some reason when it passes through to the Xero plugin, it fails to pick up the one-off fee.

Has anyone had any experience with the Xero plugin for WooCommerce and being able to pass through extra fees?

Answer (score 0):

We just struck the same issue. Here are a few edits to the plugin (woocommerce-xero.php) which should fix the issue for you. My edits are probably not the most eloquent code though sorry.

Replace lines 471-483 with the following (just some small edits).

```
        //Grab fees as well
        $fees=$order->get_fees();
        foreach($fees as $v)
            $items[]=$v;

        // Add Each item as a line item AND add fees
        foreach( $items as $key => $value ) {

            if($value['type']=="fee")
                $value['qty']=1;    
            else
                $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $value );
            $replace_pattern = array('&#8220;', '&#8221;');
            $item_description = str_replace($replace_pattern, '""', $value['name']);


            $xml .= '<LineItem>';
            $xml .= '<Description>' . htmlspecialchars( $item_description ) .'</Description>';
            $xml .= '<AccountCode>' . $this->sales_account . '</AccountCode>';
            $xml .= '<Quantity>' . $value['qty'] . '</Quantity>';
            if ( ($value['type']!="fee") && ( 'on' == $this->send_inventory ) && ( '' != $product->sku ) ) {
```